# I have created one string extension to join string with space in swift 2.0 but its not working in swift 2.1 xcode 7

Tags: ios, string, swift2, xcode7

I am new in swift 2.1 , i have created one extension for string and function name is **join**, When i converted the code from swift 2.0 to swift 2.1 my code return me error 
please help me , i am not able to understand what to do

This is extension

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Printable>(elements: S) -> String {
        return self.join(map(elements){ $0.description })
    }


}
```

Here is I am using like this

```
var channel_string:String!
        var languages = [String]()
        for var i = 0 ; i < ary_selected_channel.count ; i++
        {
           let getString_setvalue = ary_selected_channel.objectAtIndex(i) as! String
            languages.append(getString_setvalue)
        }
        channel_string = " ".join(languages)
```

The output is look like , assume  In array i have Three name ["one","two","three"] 
then output is

```
channel_string = "one two three"
```

The error is 
1) **Printable has been renamed to customstringconv**
2) **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

Comment: The error is telling you that where you're using the protocol `Printable` is now invalid because the protocol has been changed and is now called `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: `Printable` protocol is now called `CustomStringConvertible`

Comment: CustomStringConvertible required .description property. Default String DOESN'T conform to it. You are better to use default implementation of func joinWithSeparator, which is part of SequenceType protocol. see my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you receive is self-explanatory. by the way, there is easy to do the same without any complication ...

```
let arr = ["one","two","three"]
let str = arr.joined(separator: " ") //  "one two three"
```